# Loading huge animated 3D model in SceneKit causes memory issues

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, 3d-model

I have a problem with `ARKit`. My 3D model is 197MB in DAE format (without 20MB of textures). When I try to load my model in `SceneKit` without textures everything is fine but when I load it with textures my app has memory issues. My textures files are between 100kB and 4MB. When loaded with textures my app uses 1.84 GB RAM on my phone (iPhone X) and it causes memory issues. I have been searching on the internet but I could not find any solutions. Can somebody offer me help or some advice?

My code:

```
self.shipNode = SCNNode(daePath: "art.scnassets/s.scn")!

extension SCNNode {

    convenience init?(daePath: String) {

        self.init()

        guard let scene = SCNScene(named: daePath) else {
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            for childNode in scene.rootNode.childNodes {
                self!.addChildNode(childNode)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How I am using it:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

    DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in

        if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {
            let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width,
                                height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)

            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.8)
            self?.planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
            self?.planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

            self?.shipNode.position = SCNVector3Zero
            self?.shipNode.position.z = 0.05

            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

                self?.planeNode.addChildNode(self!.shipNode)

                self!.node.addChildNode(self!.planeNode)
            }
        }
    }
    return node
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question and body to make it easier to read. I also changed the tags so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. I also indented formatted your code sample so that it renders properly. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **High-poly models** with huge texture maps **are not suitable** for robust AR experience. Augmented Reality frameworks (such as ARKit or ARCore) are very processor-intensive, so there's no need to additionally increase a burden on CPU, GPU and memory.

***Why ARKit apps are so CPU-intensive***?

Your ARKit app uses 4 sensors to track a surrounding environment at 60 fps, and it simultaneously renders (with a help of SceneKit or RealityKit) your animated 3D model with all the textures, lights and shadows, and, after that, it composites in real-time a 2D render of your model (in RGBAZ pattern) over high-res RGB video from rear camera. That's too much for your device, isn't it?

Hence, any high-poly models with huge textures not only cause a memory and CPU/GPU issues, but also very quickly drain your battery. And, please take into consideration - iPhone X has only 3 GB of RAM of which iOS uses more than 1 GB, so memory issues are quite possible in your particular case.

**So, my recommendations for creating a 3D model for robust AR experience are the following**:

- Low-poly geometry (usually **10,000 polygons** per model are fine)
- UV-mapped Texture resolution – not more than **1024 x 1024** pix
- Preferably, **pre-baked UV-mapped shadows** for static elements
- Use of **JPEG format with 0% compression** for texture (PNG is larger)
- Don't use too many PBR shaders (with *metalness* property) in your scene

Comment: thanks your reply and i got  what you mean if you have any experience with unity(Vuforia) i have question i am doing same thing with unity(Vuforia) and when i converted to ios  everything is fine but with arkit i have problems

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that Unity (with Vuforia installed) reduces the number of polygons in your 3D model (optimization process). Could you check it?